# Changing directory by changing one early word in a pathname

Tags: shell, cd-command

How do I change to a near-identical path with a different low-level parent? If you’re working in for instance `~/foobar/foo/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/` and need to get to the same path in `bar` instead of `foo`, how can you get there without typing out `cd ~/foobar/bar/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/`? Surely there’s some elegant and/or kludgy solution.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/3759/1156790

Comment: By the way, you have included the perfect example, where the first occurence of the pattern should not be replaced...

Comment: Heh, yeah, I *kind* of had that in mind when writing that example. And @thanasisp more than related, it’s pretty identical, wasn’t sure how to search it though. But there seems to be a more complete answer here than there.

Comment: Using `set -o vi` you can use vi key bindings. When the cursor is at the end, you could do ``<ESC>F/;;;;lcwbar`` (i.e. search for "/" backwards, repeat the search several times (";") until the cursor is on the "/" before "foo", move one character to the right (``l``) and then ``c``hange ``w``ord to "bar". I find this approach quite flexible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In some shells, e.g. `ksh` and `zsh`, doing `cd word1 word2` would change to a directory given by changing the first occurrence of `word1` in the pathname of the current directory to `word2`.

For example, in the `zsh` shell:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/sbin
$ cd sbin bin
/usr/local/bin
$
```

In other shells that support the non-standard `${variable/pattern/replacement}` parameter substitution originally found in `ksh93`, you may use `${PWD/word1/word2}` to create the pathname of the directory to change into:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/sbin
$ cd "${PWD/sbin/bin}"
$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
```

In those shells (`bash`, for example), you could even create your own naive `cd` function to handle two arguments in the way that `ksh` and `zsh` does it, like so:

```bsh
cd () {
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [[ $1 != -* ]]; then
        command cd -- "${PWD/$1/$2}" &&
        printf 'New wd: %s\n' "$PWD"
    else
        command cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

The `[ "$#" -eq 2 ]` detects when the special `cd` behavior should be triggered (when there are exactly two command line arguments), but we test with `[[ $1 != -* ]]` to *not* trigger the special behavior if you use an option with `cd`.  Using `command cd` instead of `cd` inside the function avoids calling the function recursively.

Testing that in `bash`:

```
$ cd /usr/local/sbin
$ cd sbin bin
New wd: /usr/local/bin
$ cd local ''
New wd: /usr/bin
$ cd bin sbin
New wd: /usr/sbin
$ cd sbin local/sbin
New wd: /usr/local/sbin
$ cd '*/' /
New wd: /sbin
```

Notice that the last command replaces using a pattern matching up to and including the last `/`; the pattern must be quoted.  To disallow patterns and to always treat the first argument as a word, use `command cd "${PWD/"$1"/$2}"` in the function (notice the quoting of `$1`).

To additionally force the replacement to only affect a complete directory name, use `command cd "${PWD/"/$1/"/"/$2/"}"`.
Artificially inserting `/` before and after both arguments would avoid  matching substrings of directory names, but would make it incompatible with the way this works in `zsh` and `ksh` and it would no longer allow you to make substitutions in the last part of the directory path as there is no `/` at the end (you can only provide a certain level of hand-holding before the extra "help" starts to be a hindrance).

This *would* make `cd foo bar` work with the example that is in the question, though. You would otherwise have to make sure not to match `foo` in `foobar` in some other way, for example with `cd foo/ bar/`.

Comment: `${var/pattern/replacement}` is also from the Korn shell but came much later (ksh93). See also `$var:s/foo/bar/` in (t)csh or zsh (already in the first release of csh in 2BSD in the late 70s)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.

```
cd "$( echo "$PWD" | sed -e 's%/foo/%/bar/%' )"
```

`sed` uses the character following the `s` command as its delimiter.

Comment: You may want to read [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)

Answer (score 2):

On the cli, you can use a modifier like this example:

```
$ mkdir -p foobar/foo/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/
mkdir: created directory 'foobar'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data/images'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data/images/2020'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data/images/2020/01'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data/images/2020/01/14'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/foo/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/'
$ ^bar/foo^bar/bar^
mkdir -p foobar/bar/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data/images'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data/images/2020'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data/images/2020/01'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data/images/2020/01/14'
mkdir: created directory 'foobar/bar/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/'
```

Explanation:

The first command creates nested directories starting with foobar. The second command uses the modifier ^ to replace a string in the previous command with a new string. It is easy to make a mistake by typing the following:

```
^foo^bar^
```

However, this will change the command to

```
mkdir -p barbar/foo/data/images/2020/01/14/0001/
```

because it will also affect the leading foo. To avoid this, you can use some characters before or after the intended string.

I used mkdir in this example, but the cd is similar. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

When I've needed to work between two directories quickly and more than a couple of times the following example shows what works for me:

```
$ pwd
/home/chris/tmp
$ ln -s /home/mythtv/video/tv/tmp 
$ cd tmp
$ ls
$ cd ../ 
$ mv 852f.mkv tmp
$ ls tmp
852f.mkv
$ rm -i tmp
rm: remove symbolic link 'tmp'? y
$ ls /home/mythtv/video/tv/tmp
852f.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes it's easier to use the mouse**, assuming you're using a good terminal emulator on a graphical desktop. Or in `screen` or a modern equivalent, you can use keyboard controls to copy/paste some text.

```
$ pwd
/some/long/path
```

copy/paste that path onto a `cd` command (i.e. double-click on it to select the whole thing, or triple to get the whole line if there are spaces. If so then type a single-quote before pasting it).

Then use your shell's line-editing keys to edit an early component of it, e.g. in Bash's `emacs` mode,

- ctrl-a to move the cursor to the start of the line
- ctrl-right-arrow (or alt-f) a couple times to go forward by words until the right component.
- alt-d or alt-backspace to delete a whole word forward or backward.
- type a replacement (with tab completion) and hit return

If you fumble something, it's only a `cd` command so it won't do anything destructive.