# How to use substitute with cd command in Linux

Tags: linux, cd-command, hp-ux

We recently migrated from **HP-UX B.11.31** to **Linux 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64**.

I am trying to achieve the below (which worked in the earlier HP-UX system):

```
$ pwd
/global/app/opt/prod/ee/01/custo/src/
$ cd prod qa
/global/app/opt/qa/ee/01/custo/src/
$ pwd
/global/app/opt/qa/ee/01/custo/src/
```

Basically, it switches from **prod** to **qa**, maintaining the relative directory structure.

when I try the same think in Linux:

```
$ pwd
/global/app/opt/prod/ee/01/custo/src/
$ cd prod qa
-bash: cd: prod: No such file or directory
$ pwd
/global/app/opt/prod/ee/01/custo/src/
```

Here, the directory doesn't change.

Please help.

Comment: It looks like ksh, try running your script with ksh.

Comment: thanks @ArkadiuszDrabczyk! used 'exec ksh' and then ran it. worked fine!

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Changing directory by changing one early word in a pathname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625213)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such substitution is a function offered by the `ksh` shell.

The `bash` shell does not offer it.

Try switching over to `ksh`to resolve this.

```
$ pwd
/tmp/steve
$ cd ve phen
bash: cd: ve: No such file or directory
$ ksh
$ pwd
/tmp/steve
$ cd ve phen
/tmp/stephen
$
```

Comment: ... inherited by zsh as well I think

Comment: hi steve, HP-UX is using sh and Linux is using bash (checked using echo $0)

Comment: Thanks @steve! switching to ksh (exec ksh) gave me desired results. Sorry cannot upvote your answer. No reputation :(

Comment: Hmm... is ksh (as opposed to sh) really often just a symlink to bash though? Isn't `$SHELL` just telling you your login shell here?

Comment: @AmanS.Aneja Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about the semantics of that two-argument `cd`, but something like this might do for the simple cases. This changes the string in the first argument to the string in the second argument the first time it appears in the current directory, and prints the new directory name.

```
#!/bin/bash
cdsub() {
    if [ "$#" = 2 ]; then
        local dir="${PWD/"$1"/"$2"}"
        printf "%s\n" "$dir"
        cd -- "$dir"
    else
        printf "usage: cdsub <string> <replacement>" >&2
    fi
}
```

So,

```
$ cd /tmp/foo/foo
$ pwd
/tmp/foo/foo
$ cdsub foo bar
/tmp/bar/foo
$ pwd
/tmp/bar/foo
```

You could name the function `cd`, and then use `command cd` inside to avoid sinking into endless recursion, but Bash's `cd` takes the `-L` and `-P` options too, and we'd need to implement proper argument processing for them, too. Just checking the number of arguments would make something like `cd -P directory` try to do the replacement.

Also, the above function doesn't deal with errors too well, e.g. `cd xyz something` where `xyz` doesn't appear in the path would just leave you in the current directory instead of erroring like Ksh does.

Answer (score 0):

A bash implementation for .bashrc:

```
# ksh-like change directory
# if two args, do substitution in PWD
cd_ksh () {
  if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then builtin cd $1; return; fi
  echo "   cd_ksh: substituting $1 with $2 in PWD"
  newdir=${PWD//$1/$2}
  builtin cd $newdir
}
export -f cd_ksh
alias cd=cd_ksh
```

This will result in the same return value as the builtin cd command in all cases